# buildbot install : git poll failed

Tags: linux, buildbot

I have a little problem.

I wanted to install buildbot so I followed the doc: http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/Installation.html

For the **master.cfg**, I just copy the sample.

But when I start BuildBot I got that :

```
gitpoller: repo poll failed
....
No such file or directory: \'/tmp/gitpoller_work
```

I don't know why ?

If you have an idea,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short, configuring buildbot is more involved that just copying a generic config file.  The master.cfg.sample is merely meant to provide a rough starting point for configuring your buildmaster and slaves.  In other words, you're going to have to provide the information about your actual projects, repositories, and build environments in the config file.

If you're having trouble with the configuration, the [doc is pretty comprehensive](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/current/).  I only had a few problems with stuff more obscure than the doc can answer, at which point I turned to the nice folks - a number of their developers - on their IRC channel (`#buildbot` on [freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/)), who were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The directory that the git poller seems to be looking for seems quite strange (it has ` and \ and /). Personally (and matching the current sample config), I prefer using a directory under the master directory. The current sample config uses `workdir='gitpoller-workdir'`. If you have more than one `GitPoller`, you will need to use more than one directory, currently.

Update: With buildbot 0.8.7, there is a new `GitPoller`, that doesn't require multiple workdirs, and defaults to something sensible. If using 0.8.7+, you should just not specify `workdir`.